# How to redirect all .aspx URLs to their NEW location on a subdomain

Tags: asp.net, redirect, http-status-code-301

I recently completed a transfer of a very large ASPDotNetStorefront site (many pages/URLs) from the domain's wwwroot to a subdomain.

For SEO reasons I want to auto 301 redirect any & all OLD URLs which end in ".aspx" to their new location on the subdomain. (All paths being the same except now being in subdomain instead of wwwroot)

Example:
OLD URL= "http://www.mysite.com/c-2-some-product-page.aspx"

DESIRED NEW URL = "http://store.mysite.com/c-2-some-product-page.aspx"

I need something that will check if the requested page ends in .aspx, then redirects to the "store" subdomain. It should also make sure that the requested old page url doesn't exist

This site is running on a Windows host, AppliedI.net

thanks so much

Comment: Welcome to SO. We dont write code for you. We help you when you are stuck. Please ask specific questions.

Comment: @Shoban are you sure you picked the right reason to close? `"It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form."` I think the OP has asked a perfectly reasonable question. It's answerable, and not vague in the slightest.

Comment: The question had enough info so I did not want to close it as "not constructive" .. then It did not look like off topic too. I din't know which one to choose. sorry

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to try something like this in your global.asax file

```
// Untested, but the concept is there.
private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().StartsWith(
        "http://www.mysite.com/"))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Status =
            "301 Moved Permanently";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location",
            Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Replace(
                "http://www.mysite.com/",
                "http://store.mysite.com/"));
    }
}
```